# What versions of lazarus and free pascal are stable and compatible

Tags: installation, lazarus, fpc

AFAIK the installation of Lazarus consists from downloading it and FPC from SVN and compiling. There's a problem(*) with the newest versions and I'd like to install a stable version. However, all I have are the SVN revision numbers and I couldn't find out what versions are *stable* and what *work together*.

---

(*) Our application crashes when compiled on Ubuntu 32 and run on OpenSUZE. No idea, what's exactly going on, but this is a too complicated problem for including it in this question.

Comment: Can't you get this information from the FP web site?

Comment: @KenWhite I don't think so. They write "... Version 2.6.4 is the latest stable version the Free Pascal. Hit the download link...", but this is of no use as Lazarus needs a version from SVN, so I need the exact revision number. Similarly for Lazarus. There are different ways to install them, but they all have their own problems.

Comment: So why would you think information is available here that isn't available from the project's own site?

Comment: @KenWhite The project site owner provides information they deem useful, but there may be people needing other information. Some (like me) look for the information, others may know it.

Comment: But any answer to this question received here would be outdated tomorrow/next week/next month when a new version is considered to be the "stable" one, and therefore the question has no value to future readers here; it would seem to me that makes it off-topic.

Comment: @KenWhite Not any such answer would be off-topic. I have read the project page carefully and found nothing, but there may be a link I have missed. There may also be such an information in SVN (which I know good enough to hate but not good enough to master), or anything else. And maybe there's nothing and the best I can get is a "good pair". But we don't know.

Comment: You tried to download FPC separately (??). On http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/ you can download Lazarus 1.2.6 and FPC 2.6.4 combined. That is the latest stable release version of both Lazarus and FPC. If you mean something else please clarify and provide the URL from where you are trying to download. If you want stable releases you shouldn't have to use SVN.

Comment: @Rik Yes, I followed a short "manual" I've been given - it should avoid other problems, but this may be no more true. It was one or two or three months ago - the current Lazarus page looks very differently and *it looks like everything is below the big download button*. I'm perfectly sure, this wasn't the case as I most recently visited the page, especially the 32-bit package was nowhere to find. I'll give it a try... next year.

Comment: One click under the big button and you are at http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?page=downloads  I can't really imagine what is so difficult here.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Indeed! But do you happen to know since when it's like this? I'm perfectly sure, it wasn't always possible (maybe for 32 or 64 bit it was, but we needed both) and that's why a college of mine resorted to the complicated SVN procedure. Having all 3 packages in a single place makes it trivial, but it wasn't always the case.

Comment: Afaik the three pronged (win32,win64,wince) plugin model is several years old. The webpage in that form about two. (spring 2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both projects provide releases, and these **releases are the only ones formally declared stable**, currently Lazarus 1.2.6 (from the 1.2 stable branch) using FPC 2.6.4 (also from stable 2.6 branch).

**Lazarus mentions the prefered version of (release, stable) FPC with every release** and for 1.2.6 that is 2.6.4.

Of course the status of moving trunk is sometimes more stable than other times, e.g. currently it is quite usable because a new major (FPC) branch is imminent, an event that only occurs once every 2-3 years. But there are no guarantees there, and this branch still must go through the formal release process.

Many users from emerging targets that are not supported in the stable branches often use it though.